# Spring boot - C3P0 connection pooling with Spring Data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, c3p0

I have a spring boot(1.4.3.RELEASE) application with MySQL as a backend. Using Spring Data with Oracle UCP and MySQL Java connection for connection pooling. Things are working fine.

For, UCP connection pooling, I create a data source with the below code.

```
@Bean(name = "appDataSource")
    @Primary
    public PoolDataSource appDataSource() {

        this.pooledDataSource = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        final String databaseDriver = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.driverClassName");
        final String databaseUrl = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.url");
        final String databaseUsername = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.username");
        final String databasePassword = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.password");
        final String initialSize = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.initialSize");
        final String maxPoolSize = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.maxPoolSize");
        final String minPoolSize = environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.minPoolSize");
        // final String poolName =
        // environment.getRequiredProperty("application.datasource.poolName");

        try {
            pooledDataSource.setConnectionFactoryClassName(databaseDriver);
            pooledDataSource.setURL(databaseUrl);
            pooledDataSource.setUser(databaseUsername);
            pooledDataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
            pooledDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(initialSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
            pooledDataSource.setSQLForValidateConnection(TEST_SQL);
            pooledDataSource.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(Boolean.TRUE);
            pooledDataSource.setConnectionWaitTimeout(CONNECTION_WAIT_TIMEOUT_SECS);
            // pooledDataSource.setConnectionPoolName(poolName);
        }
        catch (final NumberFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable to parse passed numeric value", e);
        }
        catch (final SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("exception creating data pool", e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Setting up datasource for user:{} and databaseUrl:{}", databaseUsername, databaseUrl);
        return this.pooledDataSource;
    }
```

Now, I am trying to move to C3P0 based connection pooling and hence added the below property in my application.properties

## Configure the C3P0 database connection pooling module

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_size = 15
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.min_size = 6
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.timeout = 2500
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements_per_connection = 10
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period = 3000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment = 3
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.validate = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads = 15
```

and injecting Datasource a below.

```
@Bean
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() {
    return new ComboPooledDataSource();
}
```

But, it is not working. Is there anything I am missing here.

Hope, C3P0 is better than UCP.

Thanks,

Comment: Ofcourse it isn't working... You either configure hibernate to do the pooling (which isn't recommended) or you configure a datasource which does the pooling and pass that to hibernate. You are now configuring hibernate and pass a default datasource to it. Remove the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.c3p0` and configure the `ComboPooledDataSource` accordingly. (Although I would suggest using HikariCP instead of C3P0)...

Comment: I use Spring data and hence used the above props.

Comment: Those properties have nothing to do with Spring Data...

Comment: # Dialer Data Access
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=cc_dialer
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.hikari.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dialer
spring.datasource.hikari.username=root
spring.datasource.hikari.password=root
spring.datasource.hikari.type com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

Still getting error, like Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE